# Woocommerce extend tax report with custom column

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

Within Woocommerce Admin Analytics reports, inside the tax section i would like it to a custom columns. How do i go about adding this into my reports?

Picture example below of what i would like: customs columns - Date, sales etc....

[image: Example]

These are the current columns we have, the default ones.

[image: Current columns]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may consider using the WooCommerce Admin extension. WC-Admin reports are extendable so it is possible to customize them and even create new ones from scratch. You'll find some code examples and guidelines in the official extensions repo:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/tree/master/docs/examples/extensions

Check the *add-report* to create a new report and the *table-column* to add new columns to an existing one.